# sort csv by column

Tags: python, csv, sorting, parsing

I want to sort a CSV table by date. Started out being a simple task:

```
import sys
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("files.csv"), delimiter=";")

for id, path, title, date, author, platform, type, port in reader:
    print date
```

I used Python's CSV module to read in a file with that structure:

```
id;file;description;date;author;platform;type;port
```

- The date is ISO-8601, therefore I can sort it quite easily without parsing: 2003-04-22 e. g.
- I want to sort the by date, newest entries first
- How do I get this reader into a sortable data-structure? I think with some effort I could make a datelist: datelist += date, split and sort. However I have to re-identify the complete entry in the CSV table. It's not just sorting a list of things.
- csv doesn't seem to have a built in sorting function

The optimal solution would be to have a CSV client that handles the file like a database. I didn't find anything like that.

I hope somebody knows some nice sorting magic here ;)

Comment: If you simply want a tool to sort CSV files, see my FOSS project csvfix at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Since `'date'` in column has index 3,

```
import operator
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
```

or use lambda

```
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: row[3], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Does this re-write the file, or just save the sorted list in the variable?

Comment: @Jeff: It does not touch the original file. If you want to write out the results then you must do so as a separate operation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What is the difference between these two methods, what are they doing? Which one should one choose?

Comment: @abaumg: Functionally they are identical. There may be a small speed difference between them, but that probably won't matter unless there are millions of records in the file.

Comment: This is a very good, generic approach which also works if you load the data into a list of rows which than include a list of columns. Great - Thank you!

Comment: Who is looking for sort of csv data frame:
`csvData.sort_values(["date"], axis=0, ascending=[False], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 22):

To sort by **MULTIPLE COLUMN** (Sort by `column_1`, and then sort by `column_2`)

```
with open('unsorted.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['column_1'],row['column_2']), reverse=False)


with open('sorted.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['column_1', 'column_2', column_3]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in sortedlist:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Headers of csv considered here!!

Answer (score 12):

The reader acts like a generator.  On a file with some fake data:

```
>>> import sys, csv
>>> data = csv.reader(open('data.csv'),delimiter=';')
>>> data
<_csv.reader object at 0x1004a11a0>
>>> data.next()
['a', ' b', ' c']
>>> data.next()
['x', ' y', ' z']
>>> data.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Using operator.itemgetter as [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) suggests:

```
>>> data = csv.reader(open('data.csv'),delimiter=';')
>>> import operator
>>> sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
>>> sortedlist
[['x', ' y', ' z'], ['a', ' b', ' c']]
```

Answer (score 2):

for sorting csv by column, i would use something like this

```
import pandas
csvData = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv')
csvData.sort_values(["date"], axis=0, ascending=[False], inplace=True)
print(csvData)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with pandas and its easy

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("File.csv")
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["price","title",...], ascending=False)
sorted_df.to_csv('homes_sorted.csv', index=False)
```

the .sort_values method returns a new dataframe, so make sure to assign this to a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers given by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) and by [Tiina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992216/7658051):

```
fieldnames = [ 'id', 'path', 'title', 'date', 'author', 'platform', 'type', 'port' ]

# this means: order by 'id', 'path', ..., 'port'
items = ('id', 'path', 'title', 'date', 'author', 'platform', 'type', 'port')
  
with open('unsorted.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    import operator
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(*items), reverse=True)

with open('sorted.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in sortedlist:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

With this, you can

1-order the rows by multiple columns.

2-change the number of columns you want to order the rows by, without having to use the lambda expression

```
sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['column_1'],row['column_2']), reverse=False)
```

and specially, without having to add and remove the columns patterns inside the lambda expression, in case in the future you want to order other csv files by a different columns order.

e.g.

```
items = ('path', 'title')

items = ('id', 'path', 'title', 'date')

items = ('author', 'date', 'title')
```

instead of

```
sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['column_2'],row['column_3']), reverse=False)

sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['column_1'],row['column_2'],,row['column_3'],row['column_4']), reverse=False)

sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['column_5'],row['column_4'],row['column_3']), reverse=False)
```