# Sort csv columns?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
Timestamp;A;O;P;M;
22:05;5;7;2;1
22:10;2;3,4;7
22:15;7;4;3;2
```

With a python script I would like to order the header (except the timestamp. it has to be the first column). What I mean is:

```
Timestamp;A;M;O;P;
22:05;5;1;7;2
22:10;2;7;3;4
22:15;7;2;4;3
```

How can I do it? I don't have any code because I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why is some of your data comma-separated and some semi-colon?

Comment: so you just want to rewrite the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with NumPy!

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt('a.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=';')
s = a[0].argsort() # produces the indexes which would sort the header
s = np.append(0, s[s!=0]) # put 0 at the front again, that's Timestamp
final = a[:,s]
np.savetxt('final.txt', final, fmt='%s', delimiter=';')
```

Comment: Nice +1 for numpy even though I think its overkill in this situation.

Comment: File "C:\Users\ButoeruG\Desktop\xelena\prova\sort.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = np.loadtxt('finale.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=';')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 856, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence.

What does this mean?

Comment: I think it's because your header lines have a trailing delimiter.  Try removing that.

Comment: What do you mean? An extra ';' at the end?

Comment: Yes, you should have the same number of `;` on each line, but the first line has one more.

Comment: I tried addign ';' at the end of each row and I tried to remove the ';' too but it doesn't worked.
My csv file has some empty rows (;;;;;;;;;;;;) but I don't think that this is the problem. The script doesn't work even if I use a csv that doesn't has empty rows/cells.

Comment: I only get the error you're reporting if I have mixed delimiters in the file. For example in your question you still have one stray comma (`3,4;7`).

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
import csv

with open('old.csv', 'r') as i, open('new.csv', 'w') as o:
   reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter=';')
   writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=';')
   for row in reader:
      writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[4], row[2], row[3]])
```

Comment: This doesn't actually "sort" anything, it just hard-coded moves the columns.  If that's all the OP needs, it might be faster/easier to just use awk or something.  Anyway, simple, idiomatic Python is always good.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this post might help you. Check this link. [sort csv by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100353/sort-csv-by-column)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100353/sort-csv-by-column
```