# How to sort numbers in ascending order in a csv file made from python

Tags: python, csv

I want to get the scores which the user has to input then order the scores in ascending order however I am struggling to do so. Below is my code so far and it doesn't display the scores in order.Thanks in advance and your help is very much appreciated.

```
classa = input("what class are you in?")

if classa == "1":

    file=open("class 1.csv", "a+")

if classa == "2":

    file=open("room2.csv", "a+")

if classa == "3":

    file=open("class3.csv", "a+")

score1= int(input("Enter the score 1 results: "))

score2= int(input("Enter the score 2 results: "))

score3= int(input("Enter the score 3 results: "))

newrecord =score1,",",score2,",",score3

file.write(newrecord)

file.write("\n")

file.close()


import csv

import operator

with open('room2.csv','r') as csvfile:

    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in readCSV:

        print (row)
```

Comment: If neither 1 2 or 3 are entered your code will error as file won't be defined

Comment: You should find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100353/sort-csv-by-column)

Comment: @iScrE4m Thank you, however I got an error which says 'file.write(newrecord) must be str not tuple.

Comment: @BobStanley, what exactly are you sorting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the scores, 'score1','score2' and 'score3'

Comment: Yes but from where, the csv file? And do you mean each row individually?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, the csv file. The scores added together then sorted from highest to lowest.

Comment: You mean summed and then the whole content is sorted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes

Answer (score 1):

You also cannot write a tuple to the file which is what `newrecord = score1,",",score2,",",score` is creating. You need to make a string from the scores and write that:

```
newrecord = "{},{},{}\n".formmat(score1,score2,score3)

file.write(newrecord)
```

To sort existing scores you just need to call sorted on each row, using `int` as the key to sorted so you values are compared as integers not strings, set `reverse=True` to order from highest to lowest.

```
with open('room2.csv','r') as csvfile:  
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        srt_row = sorted(row,key=int,reverse=True)
```

To sum each row and then sort, sum the values after mapping to ints again setting `reverse=True` to sort from high to low:

```
with open('room2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    srt = sorted((sum(map(int,row)) for row in readCSV), reverse=True)
```

If you want to write to a file:

```
with open('room2.csv','r') as csvfile, open("out.csv","w") as out:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for scre in sorted((sum(map(int, row)) for row in readCSV), reverse=True):
        out.write(str(scre))
```

Comment: When I run the code I get an error which says 'file.write(newrecord) must be str not tuple'. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @BobStanley, if you use the code above there will be no error

Comment: Yes thanks for that. However, I am also using parts of my code above which do give me an error and I am still confused on which parts of code I need in order to successfully code this.

Comment: @BobStanley, your error is because you make a tuple and then try to write it to the file, I added how to do it properly

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you know how to add the person's name along side their score, for example, Bob 24, James 20, Paul 18 etc. The program will ask their name at the start.

Comment: Upvoting ya answer just because OP is trying to delete this post :-(

Comment: @BhargavRao, how do you know?

Comment: He's defacing a lot of his posts (See the questions revisions). He's already deleted one other of his post. Also be on vigil for edits on your post http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11305123

Comment: @BhargavRao, I am beginning to think Computer Science , Oxford might be a ruse .. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `sort()` to sort a list. 
 
For example:

```
# List 
listOne = ['5', '7', '1']
# Sort the list 
listOne.sort()
# Display the results 
print('List', listOne)
```

You can eather sort the list before writing the record to a csv file, or when reading the csv file add the values to a list and sort those.

Example 2: 
Sort before adding the values to the csv file.

```
# Declare an empty list 
newrecord = [] 

score1= int(input("Enter the score 1 results: "))
score2= int(input("Enter the score 2 results: "))
score3= int(input("Enter the score 3 results: "))

# Add scores 
newrecord.append(score1)
newrecord.append(score2)
newrecord.append(score3)
# Sort list 
newrecord.sort()
# Print result 
print(newrecord)
```

Example 3: 
Sort the values after taking the values from the csv file.

```
# Declare an empty list. 
csvList = [] 

with open('room2.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        # Add value to a list. 
        csvList.append(row)

# Sort the values from the CSV file. 
csvList.sort()

# Print result. 
print(csvList)
```

Comment: I want the numbers to saved in a csv file then I read the csv file and sort it in ascending order.

Comment: You could do that as well. Read the CVS file number, store those in a list and then sort that list.

Comment: Why is my post -1? Topic Starter aks how to sort items, I give a few suggestion and people give me negative feedback and don't tell me why?

Comment: That wasn't me, I can't upvote nor down vote an answer as I haven't reached 15 reputation

Comment: I know. I hope I gave you some clues though. :-))

Comment: when I tried to run example 3 the output was just []

Comment: Not mine but this  would error in python3 and fail silently in python3, you are mixing types

Comment: I am have tested this code in my python, and it gives no errors. But I did not test the file section. Maybe the file is not being read correctly?

Comment: @Tenzin, you cannot sort mixed types in python3 as you cannot sort string digits correctly in either python2 or 3.

Comment: Then how come Example 1 works in: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php ?

Comment: @Tenzin,  I don't need to check, I can guarantee you it does not work, I suggest you try doing it with numbers with more that 1 digit. Strings are compared lexicographically so single digit strings are not going to tell you much

Comment: If you use `sort()` with digits you should add `key=float`, for example: `listOne.sort(key=float)` Then it still will work. I just tested it.