# Trying to get my data to write to specific columns and to sorted in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, csv, tkinter

The following code works, but when I open the CSV file it doesn't 
come up in alphabetical order or in any specific columns.

I would like `name` to come up in **column 1** and the `grade` 
to appear in **column 2** next to it. I had to put this in 
Tkinter and find it frustrating that I can't get it sorted. 
I am new to this and would be grateful for any advice.

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()
#output
    def output(self):
        Heading=StringVar()
        Heading.set("Please enter student name below")
        Label(text='Name:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.n = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.n.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
#Text label
        Label(text='Grade:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.e = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.e.pack(side=LEFT,padx=6,pady=6)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Clear', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)


#write to grade csv
    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('Grades.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.n.get()])
            w.writerow([self.e.get()])


#I think it is here I need to add in some code to write the data to a certain row or column in my CSV file.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('grade')
    root.geometry('380x280')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to write each name and grade in a separate column do this:

**Switch**

```
w.writerow([self.n.get()])
w.writerow([self.e.get()])
```

**For**

```
w.writerow([self.n.get(), self.e.get()])
```

There is already a question on how to sort a csv file alphabetically which has 3 answers which may help you:

[How to sort data alphabetically in a csv file created in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472390/how-to-sort-data-alphabetically-in-a-csv-file-created-in-python)