# how to convert this dictionary list to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I concatenated some daily data files of ammonia concentration values and I wanted to sort them in increasing order of latitude and longitude using the help of this answer: [sort csv by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100353/sort-csv-by-column)

After that, when I see my sortedlist (used in the solution for multiple column sorting) it gives me:

```
print(sortedlist)
[OrderedDict([('', '7'), ('lat', '10.25'), ('lon', '72.25'), ('nh', '6150295245484870.0'), ('err', '28.55')]), OrderedDict([('', '23'), ('lat', '10.25'), ('lon', '72.25'), ('nh', '6609984397284026.0'), ('err', '42.33')]), OrderedDict([('', '7'), ('lat', '10.25'), ('lon', '72.25'), ('nh', '6150295245484870.0'), ('err', '12.24')]), OrderedDict([('', '23'), ('lat', '10.25'), ('lon', '72.25'), ('nh', '6609984397284026.0'), ('err', '10.34')])]
```

How do I write these values to another csv file?
The values in OrderedDict shown here are very small I have like 500Kb data!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the csv module:

```
import csv

my_data = (your data)   # Pass the data you want to have in the csv file here

my_file = open('csv_example_file.csv', 'w')
with my_file:
    writer = csv.writer(my_file)
    writer.writerows(my_data)

print("write Complete")
```

So to walk you through what we done here, you first have your dict of data. We then use the `writer()` function to create an object that is suitable to for writing. To iterate over each of the rows, we use the writerows() function.

EDIT: Here's a link that goes into more detail with reading and writing csv files, since it would be too long to leave in here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907

Comment: `OrderedDict ` variable name might cause issues

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, just updated! You can tell I haven't had enough coffee yet today

Comment: the OrderedDict is an array of values... And by using the above code the csv file consists of only the column name in place of values.