# How to get the first element of every line in a file and sort them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file.txt with the following:

```
('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim')

('ano', 'a', '02-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a')

('pano', 's', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')
```

I would like to sort it like this:

```
('ano', 'a', '02-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a')

('pano', 's', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')

('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim')
```

also sort it by the date like this:

```
('pano', 's', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')

('ano', 'a', '02-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a')

('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim')
```

If anyone could help me with that i would be very grateful :)

Sry for my bad English

```
def ordenar():
    ficheirocompra = open("compras.txt","r")
    lines = ficheirocompra.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        a = line[0:line.find(',')]
        print(a.sort())

    ficheirocompra.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [sort-csv-by-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100353/sort-csv-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list of tuples and want to sort by the first item of each tuple, then `.sorted` or `.sort` will do the job.  Remember that `.sort` sorts the list itself, whereas `.sorted` returns a sorted list.

```
>>> L = [('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim'),
...      ('ano', 'a', '12-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a'),
...      ('zoom', 'z', '05-01-19', 'z', 'Yo', 'z'),
...      ('pano', 'zz', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')]
>>> L_namesort = sorted(L)
>>> print(L_namesort)
[('ano', 'a', '12-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a'), ('pano', 'zz', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's'), ('sim', 'sim', '03-01-19', 'sim', 'Fechada', 'sim'), ('zoom', 'z', '05-01-19', 'z', 'Yo', 'z')]
```

Another way to do this is to use the `key` parameter and pick which item to sort by.

```
def mysortingkey(item):
    return item[0]

L = [('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim'),
     ('ano', 'a', '12-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a'),
     ('zoom', 'z', '05-01-19', 'z', 'Yo', 'z'),
     ('pano', 'zz', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')]

L_namesort = sorted(L, key=mysortingkey)
print(L_namesort)
```

You can use this same strategy to sort by date, though this means converting the date string to an actual `datetime` date.  Otherwise a date like "12-25-18" would be considered "later" than "01-03-19".

```
import datetime

def thedatesort(item):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(item[2], '%m-%d-%y')

L = [('sim', 'sim','03-01-19', 'sim','Fechada', 'sim'),
     ('ano', 'a', '12-01-19', 'a', 'Aberta', 'a'),
     ('zoom', 'z', '05-01-19', 'z', 'Yo', 'z'),
     ('pano', 'zz', '01-01-19', 's', 'Aberta', 's')]

L_datesorted = sorted(L, key=thedatesort)
print(L_datesorted)
```