# MYSQL import data from .csv using LOAD DATA INFILE with Ascending order to a particular column

Tags: mysql, csv, import, sql-order-by, load-data-infile

I have loaded data from a .csv file and am inserting it into the database using the LoadData method.

The below query is working for me:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$FILE1"' 
INTO TABLE inventory FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (@ignore ,StockType ,StockNo ,ServiceVIN ,YearMake ,CMake ,SModel ,BodyType ,Color ,Interiorcolor ,@ignore ,EngineSize ,@ignore ,Transmission ,Miles ,List ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Drive ,@ignore ,Details ,@ignore ,ModelType ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Trim) 
SET CreatedAt = NOW();"
```

**But I need to insert the data with the ascending order in the List Column. 
Is this possible?**

I have tried orderby in this query But it is not working.

Working query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$FILE1"' 
INTO TABLE inventory FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (@ignore ,StockType ,StockNo ,ServiceVIN ,YearMake ,CMake ,SModel ,BodyType ,Color ,Interiorcolor ,@ignore ,EngineSize ,@ignore ,Transmission ,Miles ,List ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Drive ,@ignore ,Details ,@ignore ,ModelType ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Trim) 
SET CreatedAt = NOW();"
```

Comment: order it before importing.

Answer (score 0):

If data volume is not too big, you can use the result of a `SELECT`statement as the data source for an `INSERT` statement.

Step by step:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$FILE1"' 
INTO TABLE inventory FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (@ignore ,StockType ,StockNo ,ServiceVIN ,YearMake ,CMake ,SModel ,BodyType ,Color ,Interiorcolor ,@ignore ,EngineSize ,@ignore ,Transmission ,Miles ,List ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Drive ,@ignore ,Details ,@ignore ,ModelType ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore ,Trim) 
SET CreatedAt = NOW();"

INSERT INTO inventory(column_list)
SELECT 
   select_list 
FROM inventory_tmp
ORDER BY column1
```

You can read more details up here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/

**Option 2:** 
You can also sort the text file before importing to Database. 
Follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100384/12263045